# Jax-rs convert to object Mule

Tags: mule, jax-rs, anypoint-studio, raml

I am using RAML for design api. 
Then I convert raml to jaxrs and get java classes (https://github.com/mulesoft-labs/raml-for-jax-rs ).
It gives two classes: interface and *impl classes.
Then I Import them into my project In Anypoint Studio. I want to use them.

But JsonToObject Transfer cannot use convert classes.

org.mule.api.transformer.TransformerMessagingException: Failed to transform from "json" to "classImpl".

I try use without interface classes. It work correct.

How to use interface and *impl Classes for convert json to Object?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem. 1. RAML need to convert using jackson 2. In Anypoint need to deserialize from the json to the object by ObjectMapper

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure your `classImp` support JSON binding using Jackson annotations. See the related [Mule documentation on JSON Support](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.9/native-support-for-json) for details.